# C Pthreads mutex values?

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

I am writing a program with a few critical sections. The thing is I need to check the value of a mutex in an if statement.

I would like to do something like this:

```
if pthread_mutex(&mutex) == 0 // locked 
  // Do something
else if pthread_mutex(&mutex) == 1 // unlocked 
 // Do something else
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [`pthread_mutex_trylock()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_trylock).

From that link:

> The pthread_mutex_trylock() function shall be equivalent to pthread_mutex_lock(), except that if the mutex object referenced by mutex is currently locked (by any thread, including the current thread), the call shall return immediately.
>
> ...
>
> Return values
>
> ...
>
> The pthread_mutex_trylock() function shall return zero if a lock on the mutex object referenced by mutex is acquired. Otherwise, an error number is returned to indicate the error

So your code would go like this:

```
pthread_mutex_t *m = /* ... */;

if (pthread_mutex_trylock(m) == 0)
{
    /* Success!  This thread now owns the lock. */
}
else
{
    /* Fail!  This thread doesn't own the lock.  Do something else... */
}
```

Comment: Yep, if successful, unlock it again. PS: I battled with it yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931026/how-can-i-synchronize-three-threads

Comment: Can I evaluate the lock and not lock it? I would like to evaluate a lock and then levy a sem_wait/post depending on a lock.

Comment: Through POSIX, the answer is no.  If you implement your own lock based on compare-and-swap then yes, you can, but keep in mind that *after* you read the value there's nothing to stop something from acquiring the lock and screwing you up.  You have to understand that there's lots of inherent race conditions in what you're asking for.

Comment: Ahh thanks, I think I will need to re-work the code and only use semaphores instead of mutex locks. Hmm, complicated topic!

Answer (score 1):

No you shouldn't try to do that. I think, pthread mutexes are made to regulate local access to some critical resource, and if at a place your program doesn't know if this actual thread holds the lock, you are using the wrong tool. I see two alternatives:

- keep a variable on the stack of the
  function where you keep track that it is
  locked here, or if really necessary
  store the thread id and compare to
  that
- switch to `sem_t` as control DS. they
  don't have this restriction of being
  glued to a specific thread that
  "holds" them, but are token based, so
  any thread that obtains the token may
  do the work that is required. (but be careful and check the return value of the functions these routines may be interrupted.)

Comment: I am trying to use a combination of both, it's quite troubling to solve the problem. I may need to re-work the whole solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if your mutex is already locked, I suggest you use `pthread_mutex_trylock`. Keep in mind that locking a mutex is an heavy operation, you shouldn't lock it just to test if it wasn't.